# python pandas for loop assign column based on which dataframe it came from

Tags: python, pandas

i am using a for loop to go through two frames to eventually concat them.

```
data_frames = []
data_frames.append(df1)
data_frames.append(df2)

For data_frame in data_frames:
  data_frame['col1'] = 'Test'
  if date_frame.name = df1:
      data_frame['col2'] = 'Apple'
  else:
      data_frame['col2'] = 'Orange'
```

The above fails, but in essence, I want to create data_frame['col2']'s value to be dependent on which dataframe it came from. So if the row is from df1, the value for that column should be 'Apple' and if not it should be 'Orange'

Comment: can you show the first couple of rows from `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: Look at `pd.conat` with with  `keys` parameter.

Comment: If you change `if date_frame.name = df1:` to `if date_frame.name == df1:`, does it do what you want?

Comment: The way this question has been stated is really confusing. Maybe an edit for clarification? Or show what the original dataframes contain, and what you want the final one to contain?

Comment: Please add a minimum working sample data set and desired result.

Comment: apologies for the confusion, the answer below was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few syntax errors in your code, but I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```
# Example Dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 1, 1],
})
# With names!
df1.name = 'df1'

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [2, 2, 2],
})
df2.name = 'df2'

# Create a list of df1 & df2
data_frames = [df1, df2]

# For each data frame in list
for data_frame in data_frames:
    # Set col1 to Test
    data_frame['col1'] = 'Test'
    # If the data_frame.name is 'df1'
    if data_frame.name is 'df1':
        # Set col2 to 'Apple'
        data_frame['col2'] = 'Apple'
    else:
        # Else set 'col2' to 'Orange'
        data_frame['col2'] = 'Orange'

# Print dataframes
for data_frame in data_frames:
    print("{name}:\n{value}\n\n".format(name=data_frame.name, value=data_frame))
```

Output:

```
df1:
   a  col1   col2
0  1  Test  Apple
1  1  Test  Apple
2  1  Test  Apple


df2:
   a  col1    col2
0  2  Test  Orange
1  2  Test  Orange
2  2  Test  Orange
```

Comment: I am getting a "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'" error?

Comment: ah wait i see what you are saying

Comment: Yep, you need to specify that `df.name = 'df1'`

Answer (score 1):

Let's use pd.concat with keys.

Using @AaronNBrock setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 1, 1],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [2, 2, 2],
})

list_of_dfs = ['df1','df2']
df_out = pd.concat([eval(i) for i in list_of_dfs], keys=list_of_dfs)\
           .rename_axis(['Source',None]).reset_index()\
           .drop('level_1',axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
  Source  a
0    df1  1
1    df1  1
2    df1  1
3    df2  2
4    df2  2
5    df2  2
```

Comment: Hum, I guess it's not super clear what the OP is asking.  Anyway, have an upvote!